# Do I need a better graphics card for 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, xorg, intel-graphics

I am not anything like a gamer so a modern Integrated graphic card should be more than enough for me but after getting a new PC with Sandy Bridge CPU (Intel core i7 2600K) I've had very shaky display on Ubuntu 10.10: Flickering screen and random red pixels whenever there are black color on the browser. My Motherboard is Asrock h67m.

As per suggestion [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65940/desktop-effects-could-not-be-enabled-with-intel-core-i7-2600k), yesterday I upgraded my Ubuntu to 11.10. Not seen flickering screen yet but the random red pixels still show up on browser.

So I am wondering whether it is a likely solution to apparently  [existing](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=intel_snb_natty&num=1)) Linux graphic issues with Sandy Bridge processors if i get an Ubuntu-friendly graphic card. And If so, what cards have shown good fidelity with Ubuntu?

Here is my Ubuntu 11.10's ispc result:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b5)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev b5)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev b5)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H67 Express Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 05)
02:00.0 USB Controller: Etron Technology, Inc. EJ168 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 01)
03:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. Device 1080 (rev 01)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 06)
```

Thanks

Comment: Intel cards have generally worked pretty well with Ubuntu (with the exception of the notorious Poulsbo/GMA500).  Sandy Bridge may be a bit too new still, with the issues not fully shaken out yet.  Unfortunately I've no short-term suggestions to offer; in your place I'd report bugs and hope a newer and better Intel video driver shows up in the oneiric-proposed repository soon.

Answer (score 2):

It's true Sandy Bridge graphics are fairly new and some kinks are still needing to be worked out, but in oneiric it is considered "stable", so it *should* work.  Bad news is sounds like you found a bug.  Good news is since Sandy Bridge is still new, bug reports on it tend to get high priority from Intel (if they're well written).

Easiest thing to do is file a bug report ('ubuntu-bug xorg').  If you don't get a reply within a few days give me a ping.

If you do want to solve the problem via getting a new video card, I typically recommend AMD Radeon cards these days.  R500 have been very well debugged, but the R600/R700 cards are quite good and probably easier to find in stores.  If you go with R600 or newer you have the choice of two drivers - open source -ati, or proprietary -fglrx.  A comprehensive listing of features supported by the various radeon chips is at:  http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature